# Compare two columns then populate another if the data is the same

Tags: excel

I have two separate worksheets that I would like to search in and then populate a column if two columns represent the same data.  I'm having a hard time explaining this so please have patience.

I have worksheet1 with column "A" having text and numbers in it.  In the same sheet column "B" has the data that I want to show in worksheet2 if Both Column "A" match in both worksheets.

---

Example:
Worksheet1

**Column A**

Text text text (2012-R-0000)

blah blah blah

text text text (text 2012-R-0001)

**Column B**

20-204

20-405

40-609

---

Worksheet2

**Column A**

2012-R-0000

2012-R-0001

**Column E**

(empty) I would like the data in Worksheet1 Column B to be placed here.

---

Thank you in advance for any assistance with my question.

Comment: `Vlookup()` should do the trick for you, then

Comment: Take a look at VBA in Excel. It is much more powerful for making comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a named range for all the data in worksheet 1 and then (as John Bustos suggested) use a Vlookup to populate the data on the second worksheet (let's say the named range is "values":

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",A1,"*"),values,2,FALSE)
```